# Passing image as a base64 encoded bytearray or just a path of it

Tags: android

I have an android app that tries to fetch images from a server.

So which one of these gives better performance and why? (In terms of time and space.)

- Passing byte array as the response to the android app

  or
- Passing only the path of the image in the server as response and retrieving image from URL in android app.

Comment: in the end it is the same, since when you pass a url it will be downloaded as a byte array

Comment: Passing only the path of the image in the server

Comment: `have an android app that tries to fetch images from a server.`. If you want to fetch the image then fetch it. Do not base64 encode it. Just fetch it. Only a path is nonsense if the image has to be fetched.

Comment: How would you fetch  it?

Comment: Well the same as you would do it i think. But not base64 encoded. Just the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends upon the quality of the image and its size ...suppose you have created an image gallery app that fetches image from the server and you want very high quality downloadable images....then you should use the image path

*BUT*

If you have an app that just uses the images as thumbnails or if the user has no use of the image you can use the base64 encoded image since its loading time is very fast and the heavylifting is done by the app and not the network...i.e loading the whole image through path takes time and much data while the base64 encoded image is just a small string which will be converted to image by the app and will minimise the loading time..

Comment: Will both methods produce high quality images?

Comment: No the encoded image wont produce image of high quality

Comment: Im not sure but a quick google search may reveal it...but according to my observation HD inages with a large size loses its quality when encoded

Comment: Not much but very minute

Comment: And moreover encoding the images takes time even if the encoded string is present directly in the database the server will have a tough time converting it if the image was uploaded or something like that

Comment: Ofcourse but that will take time too and if you are doing it through an web app you may need to use external plugins

Comment: So considering all above my images are stored in filesystem and also they are not of high quality and not downloadable which method should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest save/retrieve only the path of the image from/to the server.

Sometimes the image sizes might be too large and it can't retrieved `blob` image to your android app, but if you are storing the path of the image to server, it will not run into a problem.

I always store images in a folder and only save the image path into server. It keeps the database size small, number of queries few and size of query results small,which all means the database performs faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice to to encode images as base64 string and include it in your response.

If you chose, however, to include only the URL to the image, you can benefit from size/speed of transfer, as base64 stream is 4/3 the size of the original binary stream (33% overhead).

Also, in this case, you could cache images.